# obtengo este error : Error CS0103 The Name "InitializeComponent" cuando creo un nuevo proyecto en blanco en Xamarin para Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

He creado un nuevo proyecto en blanco en Xamarin para Visual Studio, pero, todo el código predeterminado tiene errores como el error CS0103,

```
Error CS0103 The Name "InitializeComponent" does not exist in the current context XamaTask.Android, XamaTask.iOS, XamaTask.UWP C: \ Users \ M \ source \ repos \ XamaTask \ XamaTask \ XamaTask \ MainPage.xaml.cs 14 Active
```

Si limpio o depuro el proyecto, se agregan incluso más errores solo con variaciones, como

```
The type or namespace "App" does not exist in the current context.
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/192007/